# run mutation to store new user's post return Error: Variable '$data' expected value of type

Tags: graphql, prisma, express-graphql, prisma-graphql

im using graphql-yoga and prisma i made user and post datamodel. a user can have many posts
i did like below. now according the `addPost` mutation i want to add new post that is related to current user. but graphql server return the following error

but when i run the mutaion:

```
mutation {
  addPost(title:"aa", body: "bb"){
    id
    title
    author {
      id
      email
    }
  }
}
```

give me this error: Why is this happening? how can i fix this?

```
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Error: Variable '$data' expected value of type 'PostCreateInput!' but got: {\"title\":\"aa\",\"body\":\"bb\",\"author\":{\"id\":\"5f036dc924aa9a00070c4771\",\"email\":\"bb@bb.com\"}}. Reason: 'author.id' Field 'id' is not defined in the input type 'UserCreateOneInput'. (line 1, column 11):\nmutation ($data: PostCreateInput!)
```

data model.prisma

```
type User {
  id: ID! @id
  email: String! @unique
  password: String!

}

type Post {
  id: ID! @id
  title: String!
  body: String!
  author_id: Int
  author:     User!   @relation(link: INLINE,fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  createdAt: DateTime @createdAt
  updatedAt: DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

schema:

```
type User {
    id: ID!
    email: String!
}

type Post {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    body: String!
    author: User!
}

input UserInput {
    id: ID!
    email: String!
}

type Mutation {
    addPost(title: String!, body: String!) : Post!
}
```

resolver.

```
   addPost: async (parent, { title, body }, { prisma, me }) => {
      console.log(me);
      try {
        const post = await prisma.createPost({
          title,
          body,
          author: {id: me.user.id, email: me.user.email}
        });
        return post;

      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error);

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
const post = await prisma.createPost({
  title,
  body,
  author: {
    connect: { id: me.user.id, email: me.user.email }
  }
});
```

This will add the post to an existing user.

Also if you're getting started with Prisma, I would recommend [Prisma 2](https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/quickstart-typescript)

Comment: thankyou i will try prisma 2 later.
i did like you but i have new error:
```"Error: You provided more than one field for the unique selector on User. If you want that behavior you can use the many query and combine fields with AND / OR```

Comment: Just use id or email. Don't use both. One unique identifier is enough